# Weird behavior on circuit but not tripping the breaker

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting

Two years ago I had all the knob and tube wiring in my home replaced.  Over the past couple of weeks we've observed some odd behavior on one of the new circuits.  My LED lamp will randomly start strobing and my computer will suddenly lose power (not at the same time but most nights at least one of the two will happen).  They are plugged into the same circuit but different outlets and the breaker doesn't trip.  Also my monitor is in the same power bar as the computer but doesn't lose power.

I'm assuming this circuit is browning out as the LED behavior is similar to what you see when you use a dimmer switch with a regular LED bulb.

Prior to calling an electrician are there any basic trouble shooting steps that I should look at when a circuit seems to be browning out or would all possible problems require an electrician?

Comment: Did the new work involve #14 wire and backstab connections?

Comment: @Harper I'll check when I get home.  The suggestion here is that the wire size, connection style, and/or outlet rating may be incompatible?